# Read-Share huge hash between node.js processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, process, sharding

### Situation

I have ~10.000.000 timekeys with associated JSON data points.
I need to execute a JavaScript function fn(time,data[time],params) on all this data points in series multiple times (~10.000) with varying params.

### Current approach

I use the npm module [hashtable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/hashtable) to store the data outside of V8s VM.

```
//PSEUDO-STRUCTURE

var params = [{...},{...},...];
var HashTable = require("hashtable");
var myBigObject = new HashTable();

var timeIndices = {};
for(...) {
   myBigObject.put(time,data);        //<-- many times
   timeIndices[time] = true;
}
indices = Object.keys(indices);
params.forEach(function(currentParams) {
   timeIndices.forEach(function(time) {
       var data = myBigObject.get(time);
       fn(time,data,currentParams);
   });
});
```

### Problem

I have had the following issues:

- V8 couldn't store all the JSON data, -> fixed using hashtable
- V8 couldn't process all the data because it ran out of memory, -> fixed using --max_old_space_size (64bit)

This works in terms of memory, but is very slow. How can I speed this up?

### Ideas

1. Partition params to workers (works, but is limited by available memory)

   - How can the workers share the same workload **without** each of them holding a copy?

     - in-memory database (Redis, memcached) are memory efficient, but are slow because of either these number of keys or serializing/deserializing larger JSON-blobs
     - node-mmap (storing JSON as Buffers, sharing Buffers via mmap, parsing JSON still takes too much time)
2. Partition time to workers

   - not feasible as workers are designed to work on the complete timeset
3. only keep parts of the objects in memory and reload from disk when needed (slow, but memory efficient)

### TLDR

How can I share a huge read-only JavaScript hash-object between node.js processes without multiplying the memory footprint?

### Updates, Ideas 2.0

1. Write a C++ program, load the data into memory, fire up C++ workers with embedded V8 environment. Would that allow me to run multiple V8 VMs on the same memory?

Comment: must you really need to do it in node? never think of doing it in map reduce.

Comment: The JavaScript fn() comes from a third-party and is rather complex.

Comment: I'd save the thing to a database (maybe SQLite) and run a c++ program on it.  Sounds like you just need blazing speed-You've got a trillion operations to do...  The idea of splitting the hashtable into manageable chunks was good though.

Comment: I need to run a JavaScript program on the data - provided by a third party. Huh.. maybe writing a C++ program with V8 engine and loading the js code there...

Comment: (p.s.just a blurb of a few ideas here). Some sort of clustering doesn't cut it, I guess? MongoDB may be a bit slower then redis, but it has lower serialization overhead, I'd say?
Use some sort of workload queue to fetch data from it (which is what you're trying to develop here, I guess)?
Whatever, this doesn't look like something Node.js is best suited for.

Comment: @Zlatko: Yes, I wouldn't use node.js if the evaluation program hasn't been written in JavaScript and is provided by a third-party.

Comment: How did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need and similarly found no package that would do want I wanted.  So I took a cue from the "Updates, Ideas 2.0" paragraph and [implemented a module.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mmap-object)

It maintains a single copy of the hash structure in shared memory (mapped from a file) and lets multiple Node processes on the same box make read-only queries.

It's written in C++ and uses [Boost's](http://www.boost.org/) `unordered_map` as the hash system.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: too little space in the comment, so here's a suggestion)

Here are a few questions?

1. How many 'params' elements do you have?
2. Why is the redis thing not ok for you? This should be totally it's kind of thing, hold 10mil of key/values with lots of constant-time reads.
3. Does the fn need to be ran sequentially? How long does one execution take? Does it do data mutation or just calculation, does it need to pull the object back in or something?

Here's an idea:

- I. hold the data in redis.
- II. one global `indices` key.
- III. Run x of the workers in parallel (x configurable by your number of processors, the structure of the (fn) etc). Depending on the setup, you might even be able to split this into separate node processes (on different machines even?) but they all talk to the same redis.
- IV. Each worker fn gets his time index and gets the globally shared redis handle.
- V. Each worker writes his 'local' data to a new redis database?

Which of these steps is the problem for you?

Comment: 1. Around 10.000 combinations

2. The values would be JSON-serialized javascript objects and it takes too long to parse 10M of JSON strings 10.000 times.

3. The fn needs to process all elements in sequence/order. I am not able to partition it as I'm unable to change the fn (provided by third party)

It boils down to:
- either having all 10M in memory (no memory left for parallel workers)
- having only parts of 10M in memory (e.g. Redis/memcached) but having to parse them everytime from JSON (no speed gain from parallel workers)

Comment: Did you think of mongo? It would return parsed object already.

Comment: Yeah, but is mongo using BSON deserialization faster than JSON? Is there a benchmark comparing Redis/Memcached/MongoDB for querying JS-objects to compare serialization/deserialization speeds?

Comment: Ok, just did a test. It's actually faster to save data parts in JSON and read/parse it from my SSD (~3.1 seconds) than storing it as multiple 16MB BSON-objects in MongoDB and querying it via ID (~8.6 seconds)

Comment: Ok, there's the answer then :) How about a redis attempt?
Btw it sounds like a lot of fun out there :)  Do you have to implement this as a regular project, route, batch job, whatever? Because if it was a one-time job, it would be faster to just let it run the slowest then try all the silly stuff I'm suggesting :)

Comment: Tried out Redis; as it does not support storing complex JSON objects I would have to save the data as serialized JSON. With 4.5 seconds it's better than MongoDB (~8.6 seconds) but still slower than reading from file (~3.1 seconds)